# Zend Framework 2: Catch all route and url escape

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I'm trying to create or find a route which will basically catch all.
What I need is something that can route the something like the following;

```
/some-page/some-childpage/another-childpage
/another-page
/yet-anotherpage/page
```

These urls will not be related to any module as such, they're more so an admin can create pages at any url.

I've got something which catches the routes at the moment using wildcard routing and a child wildcard route, but when I use it in the URL view helper it's encoding the forward slashes within the 'url' parameter.
Basically:

```
$this->url( 'public_page', array( 'url' => 'foo/bar' ) )
```

Is outputting `/foo%2Fbar`.

As well as not allowing /s, when trying to retrieve the url parameter, its returning the query string upto the first /.

Any help and suggestions would be great!

Regards,
Michael

Comment: I tried building urls, because I've permalinks that contains slashes, but they get escaped when the url is assembled from url helper. There's something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734810/zf2-route-parameters-with-slash . It's the same ordeal as escaping labels used to be in forms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you could do that with an arbitrary number of segments. You could specify a segment route with the maximum amount of segments you expect and then just allow them all to be optional, but that seems a dirty way to do it if you're trying to use lots of segments.

```
'route' => '/:controller[[[[/:action]/:third]/:fourth]/:fifth]',
    'constraints' => array(
        'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
        'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
    ),
    'defaults' => array(
        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
        'action'     => 'index',
        'third'      => 'something',
        'fourth'     => 'something-else',
    ),
```

You could possibly get something done with the Regex route, but again that's probably nasty as well.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-regex

I would probably suggest to use a better url structure as urls that deep aren't great anyway.