# ZF2 route parameters with slash

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2, zend-route, slash

Is it possible to assemble a route with parameters containing forward slashes?

**Config:**

```
'someroute' => array(
       'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
       'options' => array(
                'route' => 'someroute/:path',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Controller',
                    'action' => 'index'
                ),
                'constraints' => array(
                    'path' => '(.)+'
                )
       )
 )
```

**Controller:**

```
$path = 'some/subdirectory';
$this->url('someroute', array('path' => $path));
```

Results in:

```
http://host.name/someroute/some%2Fsubdirectory
```

Comment: This is absolutely intended behavior and more than wanted. `path` in your example is considered a parameter and therefore gets urlencoded. Everything else would be a security risk

Comment: that is a very unstatisfying answer. i want to map a tree in a seo-friendly way. it is impossible, that dynamic generation of subfolders is not available.

Comment: for example: i have a taxonomy tree and want the following uris:
`/taxonomy/term1/term1subterm1/term1subterm1subsubterm1/`
`/taxonomy/term1/term1subterm2/term1subterm2subsubterm1/`
`/taxonomy/term1/anoterhterm1/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `rawurldecode()` in the view solves this issue of course.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `regex` route type:

```
'path' => array(
    'type' => 'regex',
    'options' => array(
        'regex' => '/path(?<path>\/.*)',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'explorer',
            'action' => 'path',
        ),
        'spec' => '/path%path%'
    )
)
```

Comment: You will need `use Zend\Router\Http\Regex;` at the top.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, so I'm posting found solution with Zend 3 to my project.

> By default, the Symfony/Zend Routing component requires that the
>   parameters match the following regular expression: [^/]+. This means
>   that all characters are allowed except /.
>
> You must explicitly allow / to be part of your placeholder by
>   specifying a more permissive regular expression for it:

```
  'type' => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/imovel[/:id][/:realtor][/:friendly]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'friendly' => '.+',
                        'id' => '[0-9]+',
                        'realtor' => 'C[0-9]+'
                    ),
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\PropertyController::class,
                        'action' => 'form'
                    ]
                ]
```

Basically, you can allow all characters, and then check/trycatch/validate in the action.

Ref:
[How to Allow a "/" Character in a Route Parameter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/slash_in_parameter.html)